# Different product prices for existing customers

Tags: magento-enterprise, price, customer, discount

Our website sells the same products in two different areas of the site,
Buyer side and Existing Customer Side.

If we add a product "Product_1" = 100€
and are running a 10% discount,
We want to show users on the Buyer Side 90€ 
AND our existing customers 100€

Is that at all possible? 
Our existing customers will be loggin in users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use group prices to give special prices per customer group. Set the default price to 100 € and a group price for your default customer group with 90 €.

This works because users that are not logged in have the special customer group `NOT LOGGED IN`, so they won't get the discount.

With Magento Enterprise you could also possibly use customer segments to only give discounts to customers that already ordered once or other criterias.